# jquery & ajax sending data to php

Tags: plugin-development, jquery, ajax

In my jquery script I have;

```
jQuery.ajax(
        ajaxurl, {
        action: 'lu_ajax',
        status: 'enabled'
        },
        success: function (a) {
        alert(a)
        }
```

In my file.php i have;

```
add_action('wp_ajax_lu_ajax', 'lu_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_lu_ajax', 'lu_ajax'); //for logged users
function lu_ajax() {

    if($_GET['status'] != '') {
            $value = $_GET['status'];
            echo $value;
            setcookie("status", $value, time()+3600, "/");
    }
}
```

I am including the file.php in the main plugin such as require_once('inc/file.php');

However, no cookie is being set or any value being echoed, can anyone tell me what the issue is please. initially the issue that I had is that I was calling the file directly and caused wp functions to be undefined so i was recommended to use ajaxurl and then the action to perform and the variables i wanted to send over to php, but nothing is happening now.

ps. both jquery and php are in the same file.php i do not have a separate js file as it doesnt fit my purpose.

**update new issue**
As I am making the ajax call from jquery i am firing them up based on conditionals, the following is a sample;

```
var stat= true;
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: ajaxurl,
                    data: {action: 'lu_ajax', status: 'enabled'},
                    success: function (a) {
                        alert(a)
                    }
                });
        } else {
            var stat= false;
            jQuery.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: ajaxurl,
                    data: {action: 'lu_ajax', status: 'false'},
                    success: function (b) {
                        alert(b)
                    }
                });
            }
```

however the cookie is always set to enabled, meaning that the first call is only being made, the problem is not in the condition as i test it by setting it to false manually.

Comment: The wordpress way to handle js is to put in separate js file. Ajax or not. Nobody can *force* you to do so, but I'll not edit my answer to accomplish a worst practise, sorry...

Comment: I have been stuck for 3 days as I am learning how to program, so i have to do loads of research for simple stuff, i know enqueueing is the best practice and way forward, however to fit my purposes i need to print the code in the page not load it in a js file. :( what do you suggest please.

Comment: You can output the correct url through <?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?> in your file...

Comment: i already did, var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>'; but i am getting really confused as my jquery code is not in a js file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your js is wrong, you are mixing the syntax of `jQuery.post()` and of `jQuery.ajax()`

You should use

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: ajaxurl,
  data: { action: "lu_ajax", status: "enabled" },
  success: function( data ) {
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

or

```
jQuery.post(
  ajaxurl,
  { action: "lu_ajax", status: "enabled" },
  function(data) {
    alert(data);
  }
);
```

After that **the `ajaxurl` js variable is available only in admin pages, not in frontend**.

So the code above will work only in admin pages, but once you use `add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_lu_ajax', 'lu_ajax');` I think you want to use ajax in frontend, in this case you have to pass the ajax url to the script via [`wp_localize_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script).

So if the js script in which reside the js code above is names 'my_ajax.js' and resides in the 'js' subfolder of your plugin, do something like this

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
  wp_enqueue_script('my-ajax', plugins_url('js/my_ajax.js', __FILE__) );
  wp_localize_script(
    'my-ajax',
    'myAjaxData',
     array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php') )
  );
});
```

Now the in the js code above replace `ajaxurl` with `myAjaxData.ajaxurl`

Comment: how about if I have the js being output by a function in the same php file, i do not have a js file.

Comment: @GM i am not using a form, so i guess i dont need to use post? apparently $_GET is by default, how can i grab the value sent by the ajax call then?

Comment: @JoseDavidGarciaLlanos who said the $_POST is only for form?  `POST` should be used every time you *send* information/data to server. `GET` when you *require* information/data from server. However, to check data passed via POST method check the global `$_POST` array, exactly how you use `$_GET`.

Comment: ah thanks, im gona test it i think im going crazy, please bear with me this its been 5 days since i started php ajax and jquery, does it matter if I use double quotes or single quotes?

Comment: OMG IT FINALLY WORKED, the success function is firing up and the cookie is being set.but when the alert is popsup it has a 0 at the end "enabled0" where is the zero coming from?

Comment: At last line of `lu_ajax` function put `die();` @JoseDavidGarciaLlanos

Comment: awesome, now I have another issue :O gosh, in jquery i have a conditional such as, if(foo == true){make the first ajax call and set variable data to true }else{make second ajax call and send the data with variable set to false, however it seems that only regardless of true or false the cookie is set to enabled always meaning only the first ajax call is being made or something.

Comment: @JoseDavidGarciaLlanos seems a javascript problem. And I can't help you without seeing code, but this site is for help with WP not with js... try ask on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 1):

ajaxurl is set only in admin. If this is a frontend ajax (looks like it due to nopriv), you have to localize the script on enqueueing:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
function my_enqueue($hook) {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', plugins_url( '/js/my_query.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'));

    // in javascript, object properties are accessed as ajax_object.ajax_url, ajax_object.we_value
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object',
            array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'we_value' => 1234 ) );
}
```

In the JS file, you can reach the ajax_url as a variable of ajax_object:

```
jQuery.ajax(
        ajax_object.ajax_url, {
        action: 'lu_ajax',
        status: 'enabled'
        },
        success: function (a) {
        alert(a)
        }
```

See http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: thanks for that, but i do not have a js file, the javascript is being output by a function in the same php file

Comment: I got notified of your answer when I ended to write the mine. Normally I'd not post after seen your answer (that's is *generally* correct) but you mantain the OP error in js code and you use `admin_enqueue_scripts` to enqueue the script, after said is frontend... For these to reasons I decided to post my answer, sorry.

Comment: Thank you for your note! You're right..Fixing the answer